# How to get total time for workitem?

Tags: c#, tfs

I have this code, it must print total time of completed tasks.

```
WorkItemStore Store = (WorkItemStore)Tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
var query = Store.Query(q.Replace("@project", "'" + ProjInfo.Name + "'").Replace("@Me", "'" + Environment.UserName + "'"));
for (int i = 0; i < query.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(query[i][Total Work]);
    }
```

But I cannot find any field about time for completed task. Please, show the right path. :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is "Total Work"? Is this a field you added to TFS?

Comment: No, total worktime - time that i wasted to some task. 2hours - yesterday, 4 hours - today. sum = 6 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the fields that you want to sum in TFS and this depends on the process template.

- MSF Templates - Remaining Work | Completed Work | Original Estimate
- Scrum Template - Remaining Work

I think that you will need to sum Completed Work however this is dysfunctional behavior and I would query the validity of your metric.